# SQL filter by Sum

Tags: mysql, sql

How could I filter a set of elements by its sum?, suppose I have:

```
id
1
2
3
4
```

Is there a clause I can use like:

```
select * from numbers where sum = 6
```

Just to note, that query won't do that, it is an example to explain more or less what I mean.

And this clause would return 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Why doesn't it choose 4 and 2?

Comment: we need more details like the schema of your table and sample data. Nevertheless, you can use `HAVING` with a `GROUP BY` clause since you are asking to filter by sum.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want the cumulative sum equal to 6.  Here is one way using standard SQL:

```
select id
from numbers n
where 6 = (select sum(n2.id) from numbers n2 where n2.id <= n.id);
```

EDIT:

Oops, got that backwards:

```
select id
from numbers n
where 6 >= (select sum(n2.id) from numbers n2 where n2.id <= n.id);
```

This, however, will return values even if none add up to exactly 6.

Comment: This is returning the last value only

Answer (score 0):

For sets of elements of size 2, you can try something like:

```
select n.id as "ID1", nn.id as "ID2"
from t1 nn,
(select n.id, (6-n.id) as complete 
from t1 n ) n
where nn.id = n.complete
and nn.id != n.id
```

Link to [***fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9780f/9)

Comment: This is returning empty set. I replaced `number` with `id`

Comment: I saw fiddle, but I don't elements being sequentially summed and then limited till 6, maybe my question is not too clear

Comment: @juanpastas Now I think that I don't understand your question, can you add one or two short examples of data stored in the table + expected output ?